# Does JxBrowser support chromium's webview tag?

Tags: webview, jxbrowser

I'm evaluating JCEF, electron, NW.js and JxBrowser for the support of nested webview tag.
I see that electron and NW.js support webview tag but nesting is not supported.

Does JxBrowser support webview tag? sample page with webview tag didnt work. Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JxBrowser doesn't support `<webview>` tag.

In Chromium, this tag is a part extension API and is not available for regular web pages. We don't expose this API either.

The only way to embed content in JxBrowser is to use `<iframe>` elements.